# PHP Ajax button press conundrum

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to have a button execute a PHP script on a page and refresh just a div tag without any success. When I remove the $ajax part of the script my buttons change state but when I add the ajax part again nothing happens.

I need to load some content from a PHP file and then change the button's and div tags state. Some help will be very much appreciated as I can't seem to find the problem.

```
<div id="noah-content">                       
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#ON'.$id.'").click(function() {
            document.getElementById("ON'.$id.'").disabled = true; 
            document.getElementById("OFF'.$id.'").disabled = false;     

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "some.php",
                data: {
                    param: $(this).attr("src");
                }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        });

        $("#OFF'.$id.'").click(function() {
            document.getElementById("ON'.$id.'").disabled = false; 
            document.getElementById("OFF'.$id.'").disabled = true;  
        });
    }); 
</script>   

<img src="images/about.png" alt="image" id="myimg" />
<input type="submit" class="ON" id = "ON'.$id.'" value=" ON " name="submit"/>
<input type="submit" class="OFF" id = "OFF'.$id.'" value=" OFF " name="submit" disabled="disable"/>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: PHP = ServerSide, JavaScript = ClientSide. That being said, what do you expect the output of `"#OFF'.$id.'"` to be?

Comment: Off will execute the sames script but with a different value. This is eventually used to change a value in a database between 1 & 0

Comment: Define "nothing happens."  It looks like you have some server-side code mixed in with your client-side code here.  Are those the *actual* rendered `id` values?  If not, show the actual ones.  Do you get any JavaScript errors in the browser console?  Are the event handlers executing?  Is the AJAX request being made?  What is the server's response?  You need to do at least *some* debugging.

Comment: Assuming you're testing with firefox, you want to go into firebug and start with turning on the console.  If you are not seeing requests going back to your server when you click on the button, you know that there is an issue there.  There are many things that could be wrong here, starting with the $id in the javascript that everyone has already pointed out.  What is that?  If that's a PHP variable, is this block of code in a php script, so that it is being interpolated?  If not that is not going to work.

Comment: I have a loop that creates multiple versions of this div tag hence the $id to identify each button individually. The 2 actions switch a button from on to off and vice-verse. The problem is once I add the ajax part nothing happens if I press the on button

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your ids for your html tags, and the way you reference them in js, seem odd (though still perhaps valid when dropped into js or html as strings).  Looks like your trying to reference a php value in an improper way in html and js.

Second, are you getting any errors on your javascript console?  Does the ajax query complete (i.e. do you get the alert message)?  Check your JS console because that will tell you something more than 'nothing happens'

Also

I usually use the success option for ajax rather than the done method.  Personal choice.

You also have a syntax error after `$(this).attr("src");`.  The semicolon indicates the end of a line of code usually, and you put it after an element in your array/object declaration for your data.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "some.php",
                data: {
                    param: $(this).attr("src")  //Removed the semicolon that was here
                },
                success: function(data){alert(msg)}
            });
```

Comment: I get a mesasge from the constole that says SyntaxError: missing } after property list attr("src");},

Comment: @Griffin  remove the semicolon at the end of `$(this).attr("src");`  I've also updated my answer to point out this syntax error

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. There was a error in the ajax part of the script and using the console I managed to debug it.

Comment: @Griffin  Glad to hear your issue has been fixed.  If my answer fixed your problem, you can accept it marking your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with evaluating your php:

In order to run your php you have to open php tags:

```
 $("#ON<?php echo $id ?>")...
```

Replace it everywhere you want your id to appear. For debugging, open your page source in the browser and see what is being generated:

Example:

```
<input type="submit" class="ON" id="ON<?php echo $id ?>" value="ON" name="submit"/>
```